# Where can I get pre-reform spelling correction for Brazilian Portuguese in LibreOffice?

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice, spell-check, dictionary

I've just made the change from Open Office to Libre Office (Windows 7), and have a problem with Brazilian Portuguese spelling.

Libre Office comes with dictionaries for the recently-reformed (some say *malformed*) Portuguese spelling.

As I (along with many others) completely reject the new spelling rules, I'd like to find a set of dictionaries that caters for Brazilian Portuguese spelling *before* the Orthographic Reform.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS do you have? You can try searching the site for other Brazilian Portuguese extensions like [this](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/vero-verificador-ortografico-e-hifenizador-em-portugues-do-brasil) (which unfortunately seems to only support the newer spelling rules, but perhaps other extensions exist for the older rules, or an older version of this one will do).

Comment: @Karan Thank you. I've clarified the question (Windows 7). You are right; Vero is the new orthography, unfortunately.

Comment: If the official extensions site doesn't help, try asking [here](http://www.broffice.org/verortografico) or in the forum [here](http://cogroo.sourceforge.net/download/current.html). ASpell dictionaries are commonly used, so you can also try searching the net for appropriate pt-br ones. If you find something, don't forget to add it as an answer below to help future readers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one is for OpenOffice.org 3.x, so I can't say if it will work or not: http://www.broffice.org/files/Vero_pt_BR_V200C.oxt